# height chart series doesn't work in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, series

I use height chart in my project but I have a problem with series  I write function for series but in series section cant read my data and dra

```js
const series = useMemo(() => {
    const calcvolumeBuy = [];
    const calcvolumeSell = [];

    if (data) {
      for (let i = 1; i < 5 + 1; i += 1) {
        const obj = {};
        obj.price = data['qd' + i];
        obj.volume = data['po' + i];
        calcvolumeBuy?.push(obj);
      }
      for (let i = 1; i < 5 + 1; i += 1) {
        const obj = {};
        obj.price = data['po' + i];
        obj.volume = data['qo' + i];
        calcvolumeSell?.push(obj);
      }
    }
    return [
      {
        name: 'buy',
        color: '#03a7a8',
        data: calcvolumeBuy,
      },
      {
        name: 'sell',
        color: '#fc5857',
        data: calcvolumeSell,
      },
    ];
  }, [data]);
   so this is series how I use :
             series: series,
```

w a chart this is my function I write for series

Comment: It seems that [data] is not included in your return statement. Try using this instead:
`return [ { name: 'buy', color: '#03a7a8', data: calcvolumeBuy },
{ name: 'sell', color: '#fc5857', data: calcvolumeSell }, [data] ];`

Comment: Hi , You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data. You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wbpoz91L/